# With Docker, why does it seem like a container's settings are saved despite deleting the container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

Please bear in mind, that I'm new to Docker.

I'm using a Mac.

When I followed this official documentation https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/rails/, it all seemed to work, and so after testing that, I created a new directory and followed the example while changing things to incorporate other things. I was making changes to the official documentation with some things shown in this link, https://tihandev.com/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-with-ruby-on-rails/

But this time when I try to run

```
docker compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql
```

It gave me the error

```
No Rakefile found
```

So I was trying to debug what change would cause this and kept backtracking the changes, and even when I backtracked to make all the files be the same as the official documentation that had worked, I still get the "No Rakefile found" error.

Funny thing is that even after I delete Gemfile.lock and recreate it, the Gemfile.lock file gets populated instantly without any console logs about installing dependencies. So clearly, this information is saved somewhere else that I don't know.

Even after I go to the "Docker Destop" GUI client, and click "Delete" for that container among the containers listed, and then delete the Gemfile.lock file, and then rerun that command, it gives the same output as if some previous erroneous state is stored somewhere else.

Can someone please help me with what is going on here?

For a clarification on this question, even though I really appreciate answers on why doing a docker compose run wouldn't work for the first time because that is an information I need as well, my main confusion here is on why even after deleting problematic sections and after returning to what had worked before, I still get the same problem.

**Edit 1: Steps to reproduce**

These are the steps to reproduce my case.

Follow exactly the same as https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/rails/ except for entrypoint.sh. Modify entrypoint.sh as below

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

bundle check || bundle install

bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

Run `docker compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql`

This would produce a message that says "No Rakefile found"

Change the entrypoint.sh file to be the same as how it was in the link.

Delete Gemfile.lock and `touch Gemfile.lock`

(At this point I doublecheck that every file is the same as how it is in the link)

Run `docker compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql`

You still get "No Rakefile found"

Go to Docker Desktop and press on the trash bin icon to delete the container that had been created due to calling docker compose run [image: Docker Desktop]

Run `docker compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql` again, and still get No Rakefile found.

Again, note that if I had followed the link exactly from the beginning, it runs fine.

Comment: It's hard to help you with this, because we don't know what changes you made and what you've done to revert them. My advice is to do `docker compose down`, delete your directory and start over.

Comment: I'll add additional details on how to reproduce this as an Edit

Comment: Please take a moment to read the Help Center article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I really wish that you had been clear about the change that you made to `entrypoint.sh` in your original post. I spent a lot of time attempting to answer your original question -- before the edit -- with an answer that was 500 lines long with detailed steps. I could have answered your question in 15 minutes if you had been clear about what changes you made.

But it turns out that the problem is that you're editing `entrypoint.sh` and telling it *"you should expect to find a Rails app in this directory"* before you've created a Rails app in that directory.

These commands are the problem:

```bash
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

These commands expect:

1. There is a bundler-managed Ruby app in this directory
2. Its dependencies include the rake gem
3. There is an accompanying `Rakefile` in the directory with a configuration that can be understood by `bundle exec rake`
4. There are additional rake tasks defined by the Ruby app in this directory that explain how to execute the commands `db:create db:migrate db:seed`

**None of that exists until *after* you create the Rails app.**

Follow the instructions in the repository that you linked to **first**. Don't edit `entrypoint.sh` before you've completed those steps because it cannot and will not work the way you expect for the reasons I've described.

Comment: thank you very much and I truly apologize for not having that detail initially. There is still a question that remains for me though. It's why even after delete those lines, I still have the same result. Only if I had never ran those lines from the very beginning, do I not get the error. That is actually the main part of my confusion because I can't figure out where docker is storing this information of my previous run, and how this persists even after I "delete" the container in Docker Desktop

Comment: Btw, where do you suggest I put those bundle exec lines if I want those lines to be called after the rails container is up? Or do you think it is fine there as long as I first create the Rails app? (If this is not a simple answer, I'll just make a new question for that)

Comment: `docker rm $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi $(docker images -q) && docker builder prune --all` to clear your Docker state completely and try again.